# haproxy and redirecting to some other URL?

Tags: haproxy

I've spent most of today playing with haproxy as I'm interested in using it as a proxy to a bunch of websites.

Some are http, some are https and it seems to work well but I have a question where I'm swamped in the documentation and cannot find what I want.

Let's say I have `www.proxieddomain.com` and I have ACLs to allow paths like `/folderA` and `/folderB` and so on.

I want any traffic for `/invalidpath` to just get sent to either `www.proxieddomain.com`, or to get sent to `www.corpwebsite.com` which isn't behind haproxy.

What's the suggested way to do this please?

Comment: Do you want HAProxy to redirect the browser or forward the request itself? If the latter, that isn't a "redirect."

Answer (score 1):

In the frontend configuration:

```
# Define ACL
acl is_valid_path path_beg /folderA /folderB

# Redirects based on ACL condition    
redirect prefix http://www.proxieddomain.com code 301 append-slash if !is_valid_path
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official documentation](http://www.haproxy.org/download/1.6/doc/configuration.txt):

> redirect location  [code ]  [{if | unless}
> ]
>
> redirect prefix    [code ]  [{if |
> unless} ]
>
> redirect scheme    [code ] 
> [{if | unless} ]
>
> - Return an HTTP redirection if/unless a condition is matched